# How to cluster a score / probability map and get the modes (with variable numbers) in pytorch or numpy

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, pytorch, cluster-analysis

I have a 2d probability map (please correct me if I use any term wrong). Something like this:

[image: Probability map, ignore red cross]

Here yellow is a high value and violet is zero. Please ignore the red cross. It is represented as a matrix in numpy/pytorch.

You can see, this examples has two clusters. How can I find those clusters including the mode coordinates (matrix indices) and accumulated probability mass corresponding to these clusters. The number of clusters can vary in each probability map and needs to be determined automatically.

I believe something like mean-shift should work, but I am new to this field so I don't know the best way to do it. I found a code from sklearn.cluster.MeanShift but it needs as input sampled points, which seems very expensive to do for images with size of roughly 512 x 512. Can I do it without sampling first?

Comment: do you need this clustering stage to be differentiable?

Comment: This is not a programming question, but a signal processing one. Try the appropriate stack exchange site.

Comment: @Shai No it doesn't need to be differentiable.